# Render HTML for conditional routes in Next Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am trying to figure out, why my HTML is not rendering for conditional routes, actually, I have three components, one is parent `index.js` inside slug directory and two are child components `country.js`, `profile.js` inside components directory.

I want to keep same URL pattern for country and profile component

`domain.com/[countryCode]` or `domain.com/[profileUsername]`

Please have a look at the code below.

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { withRouter } from 'next/router'
import Country from '../../components/Country'
import Details from '../../components/Details'
class Type extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            isCountry: ''
        }
    }
    checkCountry = (type) => {
        let isCountry = ''
        if(type){
            const countries = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('countries'))
            let countryCodes = []
            isCountry = countries.map(item => item.country.toLowerCase()).includes(type)
            this.setState({isCountry:isCountry})
        }
    }
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps){
        if(this.props.router.query.slug !== prevProps.router.query.slug){
            this.checkCountry(this.props.router.query.slug)
        }
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        this.checkCountry(this.props.router.query.slug)
    }
    render() {
        const {isCountry} = this.state
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                {isCountry ? (
                    <Country/>
                ) : (
                    <Details/>
                )}
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
}
```

the above code is working fine as expected, but the problem is, It is not returning HTML into the view source code. Please suggest how can I sort out the above issue

Answer (score 0):

You should use `getStaticProps` to provide next.js information about your request to API so next.js could cache your API responses (or similar functions, find what you need in the documentation: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/automatic-static-optimization).

Could be useful: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export.